# Merging Features in QGIS While Avoiding Rings

Tags: qgis, agriculture

I have a large grid (~1m/feature) poly shapefile I need to get into an application controller. The controller is seeing coverage, so a feature=already applied, no feature=apply. The features can have as many nodes as needed, as long as there are no rings.

Currently, the file has too many features for the controller to handle. Is there a way to merge features automatically while avoiding the creation of rings (ie, leaving feature splits to allow featureless areas to remain outside of other features)? Doing it manually would be too time intensive.

Comment: Could you provide some sort of diagram or further explanation of what you are trying to do? I don't follow. What do you mean by application controller?

Comment: I don't know of any automated way to merge polygons without creating rings. However, you could merge the polygons, use the Multiparts to single parts tool, then manually split any remaining features with rings.